# How to get random number every x second from python to template? Django

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, templatetags

Ok so this may sound foolish but I know how we can generate random number in javascript every x seconds, but actually I just want to receive a value from my custom template tag which is frequently updating, but when I do so by calling it repeatedly through my javascript it just gives the same value, so I think template tags just calls the function on start and store the value, however I need to get updated value every time I call my tag.

My custom_tags.py -

```
@register.simple_tag
  def getTest():
  verification_code = str(randint(100000, 999999))
  return verification_code
```

And in my javascript -

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    let temp5 = "{% getTest %}"
    console.log(temp5)
}, 5000);
```

This returns me same number everytime, so is there any fix or workaround for this ?

**PS**  I dont want to reload every x seconds so it should be done using custom template tags only.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Templates are rendered at the *server* side. The browser (client) never sees these tags. You will thus need to work with an AJAX request, and update on the page through JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks @WillemVanOnsem! Actually I am not good at AJAX so can you please elaborate or provide any documentation? If you could just provide a complete answer, that would be really helpful.